# Imposing constraints on a Gaussian process

Tags: gaussian-process

I am trying to model a univariate function $f(x)$ (whose functional form is unknown) by a Gaussian process. The function is defined for $x>0$ and function evaluation for growing values of $x$ becomes prohibitive. I do know some properties of this function namely:

1. The function is non-increasing everywhere in its domain.
2. The function asymptotes to some unknown constant $C$ from above i.e. $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=C$ and $f(x)>C$.
3. The function is convex everywhere in its domain - i.e. $f''(x)\geq 0$.

Is there a way to construct a Gaussian process e.g. by choosing an appropriate kernel/kernel hyperparameters such that these requirements are imposed?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to express a bounded GP in closed form (i.e. get a closed form representation of a GP that can only be positive), but if you're willing to use MCMC for your problem, then it's possible to solve your problem.

1. A positive GP can be expressed by using an improper prior which takes value $1$ if the values of the GP are all above $1$.
2. The derivative of a GP is also a GP with a slightly different kernel. You can refer to [Rasmussen & Williams](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf#page=209) for the kernel. Roughly, if $x(t)$ is a gaussian process with kernel $K$, then:

   $$ \begin{bmatrix}x\\\frac{dx}{dt} \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal N \left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu\\ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} K(t_i, t_j) & \frac{\partial K(t_i, t_j)}{\partial t_j} \\ \frac{\partial K(t_i, t_j)}{\partial t_i} & \frac{\partial^2 K(t_i, t_j)}{\partial t_i \partial t_j} \end{bmatrix} \right) $$

   The best way to model a non-increasing function would be to set a prior on the derivative variables such that they're all negative.
3. The asymptote would be easy to model; under this framework, set the observed value of the function to $C$ where $x$ takes some large value. Alternatively, you could set a lower bound on the function that is $C$ and not $0$.
4. The convexity would be modelled in exactly the same way as the non-increasingness. The second derivative of a GP (if you use an appropriate kernel, like the RBF, would also be a GP). Set an improper prior that takes value $1$ whenever the second derivative is positive.

---

As a proof of concept that this *can* be done, on [my blog](http://www.falmity.com/stats/r/nmntr/) I've modelled a cumulative distribution function using a GP (highly inefficient btw) such that the GP is smooth, non-decreasing, differentiable and where its derivative (the density) is always positive. I used Stan in R to draw samples from this GP using the priors that I talked about, and I used `autograd` in Python to obtain the covariance matrix (you can find the code in my blog, under an attached file called `mat_worker_two.py`).

I would say that it's not trivial to model such a function, but it is certainly possible. You lose a lot of the benefits of the GP however, like the closed-form-ness of the solution. You could also just model a spline instead of the GP, but I chose the GP so that I can sample from its posterior.